Round trip serialization and deserialization of Swift Date does not pass equality check
The following test case in swift does not succeed.
import Foundation
import Testing

struct TestGrouping {
    @Test func formattingWorks() async throws {
        let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        let curDate = Date.now
        let date: Date = dateFormatter.date(
            from: dateFormatter.string(from: curDate))!

        #expect(curDate == date)
    }
}

Based on the feedback of the test suite, the two dates do look identical as expected. What is happening there?
  Test formattingWorks() started.
  Test formattingWorks() recorded an issue at TestFormatting.swift:21:9: Expectation failed: (curDate → 2024-11-03 17:28:27 +0000) == (date → 2024-11-03 17:28:27 +0000)
  Test formattingWorks() failed after 0.006 seconds with 1 issue.
  Suite TestGrouping failed after 0.006 seconds with 1 issue.
  Test run with 1 test failed after 0.006 seconds with 1 issue.

I did change the #expect statement to the following
#expect(curDate.timeIntervalSince1970 == date.timeIntervalSince1970

And then indeed it seems the two date objects are not equal
  Test formattingWorks() recorded an issue at TestFormatting.swift:18:9: Expectation failed: (curDate.timeIntervalSince1970 → 1730655168.151483) == (date.timeIntervalSince1970 → 1730655168.0)

How can I make proper round-trip conversions for these dates?
I tried to pin down the time-zone, also by dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current but still the Date objects differ.

curDate includes fractional seconds. Your conversion to/from a date format string is rounding the result to the nearest second. Why are you trying to use ISO8601DateFormatter to serialize a Date?

That makes sense, it really confused me for a bit. I am writing test cases and wanted to de-serialize ISO8601 formatted strings to load data for my test-cases. Since in the actual application logic I don't actually de-serialize strings the imprecision of the string formatting does not bite me. Thanks for solving my problem.

Interestingly, I cannot create a formatter that includes all the fractional digits of seconds. It always rounds it to 2 or 3 digits.

Why are you writing unit tests for Foundation types?

@JoakimDanielson I use the unit test frameworks often to verify my assumptions about standard library functions. More convenient than a repl to check things out as I can edit back and forth. Its a nice sandbox environment actually. My goal is not to add a test suite to the foundation types. I assume apple verifies their code.

Ok so it's not really your project/app you are testing. Interesting, personally I prefer to use a playground if I want to learn or verify something like this.

When you use ISO8601DateFormatter the time part is restricted to whole seconds, HH:mm:ss, so if you want to compare the result of the formatter you need to "round" your reference date down to seconds.
One way is to use DateComponents
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: curDate)
let roundedDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!

or use TimeInterval
let interval = curDate.timeIntervalSince1970.rounded(.towardZero)

Now both tests will return true
#expect(roundedDate == date)
#expect(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval) == date)

